# Ask for a question about independence of random variable from an event

Tags: probability

Consider two independent tosses of a fair coin. Let random variable X take the value 0 if the first toss is a head and take the value 1 if the first toss is a tail. Let A be the event that the number of heads if even.

```
P(X=0)=0.5
P(X=1)=0.5
P(A)=0.5
P(X=0 and A)=0.25
P(X=1 and A)=0.25
```

so

```
P(X=x and A)=P(X=x)P(A)
```

for all x

We can say that the random variable X is independent of the event A.

Then if the coin is biased. The the probability of head is 0.8 and the probability of tail is 0.2.

```
P(X=0)=0.2
P(X=1)=0.8
P(A)=0.68
P(X=0 and A)=0.04
P(X=1 and A)=0.64
```

so

```
P(X=x and A) != P(X=x)P(A)
```

for all x

My question is :
Why if the coin is fair, X is independent of A. However if the coin is biased, it's not the same conclusion.
I'm a little confused. Could independence be a coincidence instead of the essence of two event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no coincidence here.
We learn nothing from $A$ about $X$ only if the coin is fair
(otherwise the fact that both tosses produced the same outcome enhances
our belief that the outcome was the more likely one) or "one-sided" (i.e., $P(X=0)=0$ or $P(X=1)=0$).

When the coin is not fair, the [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) of $A$ and $X$ is non-zero: if $P(X=0)=p$, then

\begin{align}
 P(X=1)&=1-p \\
P(A)&=p^2+(1-p)^2\\
P(\neg A)&=2p(1-p)\\
P(X=0 \;\&\; A)&=p^2\\
P(X=0 \;\&\; \neg A)&=p(1-p)\\
P(X=1 \;\&\; A)&=(1-p)^2\\
P(X=1 \;\&\; \neg A)&=p(1-p)\\
\end{align}

therefore

\begin{align}
I(X;A)&= p^2\log\frac{p^2}{p\times (p^2+(1-p)^2)} \\
  &+ p(1-p)\log\frac{p(1-p)}{p\times 2p(1-p)} \\
  &+ (1-p)^2\log\frac{(1-p)^2}{(1-p)\times (p^2+(1-p)^2)} \\
  &+ p(1-p)\log\frac{p(1-p)}{(1-p)\times 2p(1-p)} 
\end{align}

which is zero only when $p=0,1/2,1$:

[image]

$0$ and $1$ are actually trivial: events whose probability is $0$ or $1$ are independent from all events.

Comment: very nice graphic on mutual information, $+1$.

Comment: Lol, thank you very much. A wonderful answer!